# Variable of type that conforms to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have a `struct` that conforms to a protocol. That protocol specifies a variable that needs to conform to another protocol. In my `struct` I want to declare that variable using a specific type that conforms to the needed protocol.

The code, which should make it a lot more clear:

```
protocol ViewModel {
    var isActive: Bool { get }
}

struct TestViewModel: ViewModel {
    var isActive = false
}


protocol View {
    var viewModel: ViewModel { get }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var viewModel: TestViewModel
}
```

Using the above code, I will get a compiler error saying that the type `TestView` does not conform to protocol `View`. I would have expected that since `TestViewModel` conforms to `ViewModel`, that this would be okay, but apparently not.

Is there any way I can do what I want? I need to have the `viewModel` type casted to `TestViewModel` when using it in my `TestView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to work with generics (associatedtype in protocols)

```
protocol ViewModel {
    var isActive: Bool { get }
}

struct TestViewModel: ViewModel {
    var isActive = false
}

protocol View {
    associatedtype V: ViewModel
    var viewModel: V { get }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var viewModel: TestViewModel
}
```

This should works, you are telling to the struct that viewModel should be some class that implements ViewModel protocol

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This might have changed in Swift since this answer, but you should use `associatedtype` instead of `typealias`.

Comment: Thanks @gnarlybracket